# Passing information from a dialog to the activity

Tags: string, android-intent, dialog

I want to pass a String from a dialog to the main activity.

Can I do that with an intent? And get the extra with `OnResume`?

Comment: I think you can do this by assigning an activity class level variable from the dialog.  Can you include the relevant code?

Comment: Actually, I think you answered my question! Thanks a lot, going to try it now :)